# vuetify tags with chips using , instead of hitting enter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

in my vuetify project I have something like this

```
 <v-select
    v-model="data.emails"
    label="Add multiple recipent by hitting enter"
    multiple
    tags
    chips
    solo

></v-select>
```

This works just fine. But it only works when I hit enter. I want to achieve it using a `,` because I will be pasting many items such as emails. That's why I want to get ride of hitting enter.

Is there any ways to paste many coma separated emails and get the chips as selected in an array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for similar behavior is apparently planned for v1.1:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3287

I'll copy temporary solution from one of the comments.
@jakarn wrote:

> for example:
>   add `ref="tags"` to your `v-select` component
>   add `@keyup.space="updateOnSpace('tags')"` to the component then
>   add the `method`: `updateOnSpace(tags) { this.$refs[tags].onEnterDown(); },`

---

As for pasting text value (`search-input` will catch the value) with delimiters and setting it as selected data, you can listen to `paste` event and then append split (by arbitrary delimiter) values to selected-values array:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKEQZY

Comment: supper solution